# SupportsNoItemContext in Outlook addin doesn't work

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have a simple outlook addin which appears on the `MessageReadCommandSurface`, however since the beginning we have a problem that the addin is disabled (greyed out) when users don't have any mail open, or when they have some sort of secure/encrypted mail open (e.g. mails from Microsoft). It is getting more and more common, which basically makes our addin useless most of the time.

We used to have the addin as COM earlier, which allowed it to be used anywhere (and still does), but we abandoned COM's as they are a pain to install and we also want it to be available on the web outlook version.

I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/contextless
And tried to change the manifest accordingly, but it doesn't make any difference. It requires 1.13, but according to docs, `Support for 1.13 is available from Version 2304 (Build 16327.20248).`.
I'm testing it in a standalone desktop Outlook 2019 with `Version 2311 (compilation 17029.20068, Quick install)` and it just makes no difference.

Is there any way to make the addins at least open on encrypted mails too? Some other extension point? I don't need to read the mail contents, I tried changing the manifest permissions too but it didn't help.

The Viva Insights addin can do this, I found it's manifest and tried to imitate it 1:1 but it didn't work. Guess there's some hole for Microsoft-made addins.

Our manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0" xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0" xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>df1a391f-7431-4c1c-a7dc-8599cb8bef2e</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
  <ProviderName>Company</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="TestAddin"/>
  <Description DefaultValue="Addin description"/>
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://example.com/icon-64.png"/>
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://example.com/icon-128.png"/>
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://example.com"/>
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://example.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://microsoft.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://office.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://example.com/"/>
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity" EntityType="MeetingSuggestion" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasKnownEntity" EntityType="Address"/>
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
        <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
          <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
        </bt:Sets>
      </Requirements>
      <Hosts>
        <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
          <DesktopFormFactor>
            <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
              <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                  <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                  <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                    <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                      <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                    </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                      <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                    </Action>
                  </Control>
                </Group>
              </OfficeTab>
            </ExtensionPoint>
          </DesktopFormFactor>
        </Host>
      </Hosts>
      <Resources>
        <bt:Images>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://example.com/16.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://example.com/32.png"/>
          <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://example.com/80.png"/>
        </bt:Images>
        <bt:Urls>
          <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://example.com/"/>
        </bt:Urls>
        <bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="TestAddin"/>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="TestAddin"/>
        </bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:LongStrings>
          <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying TestAddin."/>
        </bt:LongStrings>
      </Resources>
      <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
        <Requirements>
          <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.13">
            <bt:Set Name="Mailbox"/>
          </bt:Sets>
        </Requirements>
        <Hosts>
          <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
            <DesktopFormFactor>
              <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
                  <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                    <Label resid="GroupLabel"/>
                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                      <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                      <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label"/>
                        <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"/>
                      </Supertip>
                      <Icon>
                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
                      </Icon>
                      <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                        <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url"/>
                        <SupportsNoItemContext>true</SupportsNoItemContext>
                      </Action>
                    </Control>
                  </Group>
                </OfficeTab>
              </ExtensionPoint>
            </DesktopFormFactor>
          </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
          <bt:Images>
            <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://example.com/16.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://example.com/32.png"/>
            <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://example.com/80.png"/>
          </bt:Images>
          <bt:Urls>
            <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://example.com/"/>
          </bt:Urls>
          <bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="TestAddin"/>
            <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="TestAddin"/>
          </bt:ShortStrings>
          <bt:LongStrings>
            <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying TestAddin."/>
          </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
    </VersionOverrides>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: I have a similar issue, would be keen to learn how to solve it

Comment: Are you connecting your Outlook to online service account or to an on-premises Exchange Server? I assume the former? At this point, for online accounts, any 3rd party add-in is expected to be capable of the same functionality as Viva Insights - there is no special treatment related to SupportsNoItemContext for Viva Insights that exists in the product.

Comment: @OlegO-MSFT I'm using an online account from my organization. We don't have any on premise Exchange server. Addin is registered via the admin center on Microsoft's page, but I have also experimented by manually adding the manifest file in my local Outlook and effect was the same. Button is greyed out on most of mails (some sort of security?), and gets visible only when a mail is being read.

Comment: Are you saying, there are cases where Viva Insights is not greyed out, but your add-in is? Can you give me specific example(s) please?

Comment: @OlegO-MSFT Sure. An example: when reading some emails from e.g. microsoft (like an undelivered mail notice) only the Viva Insights addin is available, others including mine or even "Send to OneNote" are greyed out. I think there were more such cases

Comment: This is not expected. As an update, I wasn't able to reproduce this on my Outlook - I've installed your add-in manifest exactly as it appears above and your button does work well and is NOT greyed out for undelivered mail notices and other SupportsNoItemContext scenarios. I'm following up further to understand why your Outlook version has this not working. Could you please share a screenshot of the product information section (File > Office Account) and a screenshot of the "about outlook" dialog? Please redact out any private info such as email address, license and session IDs.